# How do I wrap $display so it only prints if DEBUG is defined?

Tags: system-verilog

In pseudo-Verilog/Python, here's what I'd like to do:

```
`define DEBUG

task debug_print(*args);
  `ifdef DEBUG
    $display(*args);
  `endif
endtask

initial
  int x = 3;
  debug_print("X is %0d", x); // only prints if DEBUG is defined
end
```

This avoids having to add the `ifdef-endif` pair to every debug print statement. The obvious problem is that even though `$display()` can take a variable number of arguments, I don't know of a way for user-defined tasks to accomplish that, so I'm not sure how I'd be able to wrap `$display()`.

Is there a way for user-defined tasks to accept a variable number of parameters? If not, how do you accomplish debug prints without putting each statement within an `if` or `ifdef` clause?

Comment: The only issue with this will be that toggling between DEBUG and not DEBUG is a recompile, which on a large design could take a bunch of time. You could also look into the same think using $test$plusargs to make this a runtime decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to construct a string and pass that to your debug task:

```
`define DEBUG

module tb;

task debug_print(string str);
    `ifdef DEBUG
        $display(str);
    `endif
endtask

initial begin
    int x = 3;
    debug_print($sformatf("X is %0d", x)); // only prints if DEBUG is defined
end

endmodule
```

A common practice is to use `$sformatf` to build up the string you want to display.  This is similar to the UVM `` `uvm_info `` macro.

Answer (score 2):

just another variant of it:

```
`define DEBUG

module tb;
  `define dp(statement) `ifdef DEBUG $display``statement `endif
  
initial begin
    int x = 3;
   `dp(("X is %0d", x)); // need double parnens here: ((...))
end

endmodule
```

Comment: @serge, you don't need the double-backticks, a space will do. This is is a general macro mechanism for dealing with system tasks that take a variable number of arguments